# Trying to install forever from npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

Forever from NPM installs just fine, but when I try and use it it gives me the following error

```
root@bray:/home# forever start bundle/main.js
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
info:    Forever processing file: bundle/main.js
```

Comment: That doesn't look like an error. Does it not work? Try running not in daemon node - forever bundle/main.js

Comment: do `forever list` to see if your node process is running in the background. Most probably it is.

Comment: It's a warning but not an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks normal.

To check if you do actually have an error if your app isn't starting up

```
forever list
```

Then look for your meteor app in there. If it is there cat its logs

```
cat path_to_log_file_reported_by_forever
```